# Wordpress REST API is sending HTML having script instead of JSON

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am sending request to WordPress REST API endpoint -
`https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments`.

But it is not sending JSON as response.
Instead, it is sending HTML having script tag as follows -

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      document.cookie =
        "_test=<cookie value> ; expires=<expiary date>; path=/";
      document.location.href =
        "https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments";
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here, 1) a cookie named *_test* is getting created, 2) After that, it is redirecting to the requested URL with `document.location.href`.

So, when I am trying to parse the response using `JSON.parse` method, then it is failing, as it is in HTML format.
But, when I am entering the endpoint URL in browser search bar, then  `document.location.href` method inside the script of the response is helping to redirect to the expected JSON.

My expected response should be like this

```
[{"id":1,"post":1,"parent":0,"author":0,"author_name":"A WordPress Commenter","author_url":"https:\/\/wordpress.org\/","date":"2022-07-22T16:38:55","date_gmt":"2022-07-22T16:38:55","content":{"rendered":"Comment 1"}}, /*...*/]
```

Now, how to get response as JSON directly, instead of HTML?

Comment: Are you attempting to call a specific endpoint? From your example, it doesn't appear so. Also, which request type are you using?

Comment: @DouglasKorinke I want to get comments using GET method

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing. In your code you are using JavaScript to redirect the page to the json data, not fetch the information.

Try this and check your console. You should be able to take it from there.

```js
const url = "https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments";
const comments = getComments( url );

// My function
async function getComments( url ) {
    // Try to fetch the url
    await fetch( url )
        .then( function ( response ) {
        console.log( response );

        // Get the status
        console.log( "Status code: " + response.status );

        // The API call was unsuccessful
        if ( response.status > 299 ) {
            throw new Error( finalError );

        // The API call was successful
        } else {
            return response.json();
        }
        })
        .then( function ( data ) {
        // This is the response data as a text string
        console.log( data );

        // Make sure we have data
        if ( data.length == 0 ) {
            throw new Error( finalError );
        }

        // Only continue if not null or empty
        if ( data[0] !== null && data[0] !== undefined && data.length > 0 ) {

            // Iter through each item
            for ( let d = 0; d < data.length; d++ ) {
            
                // Log it
                console.log( data[d] );
            }
        }
        })
        .catch( function handleError( error ) {
            console.log( error );
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: I am not using Javascript to redirect. I am using ```fetch("http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments")``` to get JSON response from WordPress. I can't get response in JSON format. I get response in HTML format.

Comment: When I try to fetch data from ```http://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/comments``` on my localhost, then Wordpress gives me comments in JSON format. But when I try to fetch from ```https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments``` on my remote website, then Wordpress gives me response in HTML format. The response is what I provided in my question. I don't know why the response type is unusual.

Comment: Response code is 200 everywhere

Comment: I disabled endpoint for comments using [WP REST API Controller](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-api-controller/). Still I am getting same response in HTML with 200 code.